# Serializing element into custom Hybris CacheRegion

Tags: caching, sap-commerce-cloud

Info: using Hybris 5.7

I've being trying to write a custom CacheRegion in order to use Redis for this purpose (instead of the in memory solutions provided such as Maps or EHCache).

Following the instructions provided [here](https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=release5&title=Region%20Cache) didn't seem to be enought.

The point that I'm stuck is the moment to serialize the element object wich doesn't implement serializable so I can't get to serialize it into json or byte array or anything else (tried with Jackson, Kryo, FST and java default serializer).

The code is something as follow (skipping other parts):

```
...
  @Override
  public Object getWithLoader(CacheKey cacheKey, CacheValueLoader cacheValueLoader) throws CacheValueLoadException {
    return Optional.ofNullable(get(cacheKey))
        .orElseGet(() -> {
          Object element = cacheValueLoader.load(cacheKey);

          //Can't get to serialize *element* to store it
          return element;
        });
  }
...
```

Debugging I found out that Object element is actualy an instance of *GenericBMPBean$GenericItemEntityStateCacheUnit* and it seems to contains a lot of things (except the actual data that I couldn't find, oddly).

Another thing that I didn't understand yet is the usage of the CacheKey.CacheUnitValueType wich seems to be ignored by the EhCache implementation. Even when it is *NON_SERIALIZABLE* it is stored into the EhCache.

**So my question is: How should I manage to serialize this kind of data?**

**Plus question: what is the desired usage of the flag *CacheUnitValueType* ?**

The main goal behind this is to decouple the cache from the application JVM and increase HA and scalability.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The point that I'm stuck is the moment to serialize the element object wich doesn't implement serializable so I can't get to serialize it.

An object which doesn't implement Serializable in hybris should not be serialized. You have to take care of what get cached.

It's stated in the [documentation](https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8c392bd686691014ae1bf4af383a81d5.html)

> It is not possible on entity and type system regions because of not serializable object nature.